# Pandas DataFrame with categorical columns from a Parquet file using read_parquet?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I am converting large CSV files into Parquet files for further analysis. I read in the CSV data into Pandas and specify the column `dtypes` as follows

```
_dtype = {"column_1": "float64",
          "column_2": "category",
          "column_3": "int64",
          "column_4": "int64"}

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=_dtype)
```

I then do some more data cleaning and write the data out into Parquet for downstream use.

```
_parquet_kwargs = {"engine": "pyarrow",
                   "compression": "snappy",
                   "index": False}

df.to_parquet("data.parquet", **_parquet_kwargs)
```

But when I read the data into Pandas for further analysis using `from_parquet` I can not seem to recover the category dtypes.  The following

```
df = pd.read_parquet("data.parquet")
```

results in a `DataFrame` with `object` dtypes in place of the desired `category`.

The following seems to work as expected

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

_table = (pq.ParquetFile("data.parquet")
            .read(use_pandas_metadata=True))

df = _table.to_pandas(strings_to_categorical=True)
```

however I would like to know how this can be done using `pd.read_parquet`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is fixed in `Arrow 0.15`, now the next code keeps the columns as categories (and the performance is significantly faster):

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({'foo': list('aabbcc'),
                       'bar': list('xxxyyy')}).astype('category')

df.to_parquet('my_file.parquet')
df = pandas.read_parquet('my_file.parquet')
df.dtypes
```

Comment: Does this depend on which engine is used? (`pyarrow` vs `fastparquet`)

Comment: Yes, that's for pyarrow, not sure about fastparquet

Comment: for a 100mb csv file do you know if it's worth switching to parquet?

Comment: @Topde sure, switching to parquet not only brings speed but also preserves types of columns and structure of the data. Parquet files can store multi index, column types (especially categorical and datetime) which makes sense to use parquet over CSV for the correctness of the data (and also speed).

Comment: >"preserves types of columns". Unfortunately with Pandas it doesn't preserve the types, as shown by this question and some other questions. Read DataFrame. Try `pandas.DataFrame({'foo': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1]}).astype("category")`. `df.dtypes` shows `categorical`, but after reloading from parquet it's back to int64. Tested with pyarrow==9.0.0.

Comment: Parquet (at least the pyarrow-powered) doesn't preserve types of columns in a dataframe. That can easily be tested.

Answer (score 3):

We are having a similar problem.
When working with a multi file parquet are work around is as follows:
Using the [Table.to_pandas() documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html?highlight=to_pandas#pyarrow.Table.to_pandas) the following code may be relevant:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
dft = pq.read_table('path/to/data_parquet/', use_pandas_metadata=True)
df = dft.to_pandas(categories=['column_2'] )
```

the `use_pandas_metadata` works for the dtype `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: for a 100mb csv file do you know if it's worth switching to parquet?